# Find $x,y$ if LCM $= x+y$ and HCF $= x-y$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I have been struggling on this homework question for quite a while.

> Find $x,y$ if LCM $= x+y$ and HCF $= x-y$

Here is my working:

Since, LCM $\times$ HCF $= xy$,

$$ (x+y)(x-y) = xy \\ x^2 - y^2 = xy $$

I am stuck here...

Comment: @BrianMoehring My school teacher gave me this question, I also thought it's impossible.

Comment: Hint: $x^2-y^2=xy$ is equivalent to $\left(\dfrac xy\right)^2-1=\dfrac xy$.

Comment: @IAmAGuest True, if $y\ne 0$. $x=y=0$ is a perfectly valid solution for that equation.

Comment: @Andrei: goes without saying.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $z=HCF=\gcd(x,y)$. Then $$x=x_1z\\y=y_1z$$where $\gcd(x_1,y_1)=1$.
Then we have $$HCF=x-y\\z=x_1z-y_1z$$
Assuming $z\ne 0$, then $$x_1-y_1=1$$
Proceed in the same way with the other information:$$LCM=x+y\\x_1y_1z=x_1z+y_1z$$
Same as before, if $z\ne 0$, you get $$x_1y_1=x_1+y_1$$
Using $x_1=1+y_1$ from a previous equation, we get $$y_1(1+y_1)=1+y_1+y_1$$or $$y_1^2-y_1-1=0$$
This equation does not have integer solutions. So we need to go back and check the $z=0$ case, where $x=y=0$.